# How to proceed an If statement depending on a date in a cell, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a datalogger programme and I need to write a piece of excel VBA code to create a running total of certain pieces of information for a given month. I.e. if the entry was made during January and the entry is of a certain type, then a running total of however many entries of that type is made in a summary sheet. I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 Dim DateCheck As Range

Set DateCheck = Worksheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").End(xlDown)
Set SumCountLim1 = Worksheets("Jan").Range("Data_Start").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3)
Set SumCountLim2 = Worksheets("Jan").Range("Obs_Start").End(xlDown)

If DateCheck.Value Like "##-01-##" Then        '-Should I use the month worksheet funct here?'
     Sheets("Site Visit Summary").Range("DateJan").Offset(17, 0).Value = 2

     Sheets("Site Visit Summary").Range("DateJan").Offset(1, 0) = _
     Sheets("Site Visit Summary").Range("DateJan").Offset(1, 0).Value + _
     Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(SumCountLim1, SumCountLim2), "Housekeeping and Other Hazards")
Else 
End If
```

I hope my explanation is clear. Thank you in advance!

P.S. I used the Microsoft datepicker in a userform to allow the user to pick the date of entry. I don't know if this added information helps!

Comment: `Like "##-01-##"` assumes formatting. Work with the `Date`, not strings.  Just use the VBA [Month function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

It appears that you don't have an `End if`, or an

`if DateCheck.value = Month(<Cell_Location_Of_Month) Then <some_action_here>`

or

`if  DateCheck.value = Month(<Cell_Location_Of_Month) goto <some_location_here>`

or

```
if DateCheck.value = Month(<Cell_Location_Of_Month) Then
    'Some_Action_here
else
    'Some_Other_Action_Here
end if
```

Comment: Ahh, I did actually include all the relevant syntax for an if statement in my code, I just didn't include it in my question. Apologies! Just edited it to include the End if

Comment: I had a feeling it wasn't that easy. Check my above edit for a data check against a specific month. Use the `Month()` function to parse the month number